# Change Date Format using Existing Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

I have a table that contains 20,000 rows. I want to change my existing date format from 2016-04-04 to 4/4/16. I have googled it but I only found the solution for changing to the current time. This is my query.

```
UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
SET Target_Hire_Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 103)
```

But this query only for the current time which is not working for my problem.

Comment: Do **not** store dates as VARCHAR. Store them in a `DATE` column.

Comment: Have a look in this site http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: the format you indicated (4/4/16) is not 103 (dd/mm/yyyy) it seems 3 (dd/mm/yy); as @a_horse_with_no_name says, store dates in a DATE column

Answer (score 1):

Use your date column instead.

```
UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
SET Target_Hire_Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [YOUR-DATE-COLUMN], 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
SET Target_Hire_Date =
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(@a as DATE),103)
```

Comment: u mean like this? UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
SET Target_Hire_Date =
CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),CAST(@Target_Hire_Date as DATE),103)

Answer (score 0):

to have exactly the format d/m/yy, try this:

```
UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
 SET Target_Hire_Date = convert(nvarchar,day(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE)) + '/'
 + convert(nvarchar,MONTH(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE)) + '/' +
 convert(nvarchar,RIGHT(YEAR(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE),2))
```

just supposing the YOUR_EXISTING_DATE is DATETIME 
is better to store dates in a DATE column, then choose the format with the query

Comment: it's working but it convert to today date. in my case, im using my existing date in my table, just want to convert format. really appreciate your help

Comment: change getdate() with your existing date (I wrote the query based on the example in question)

Comment: if i want to update 20000 rows. how am i gonna use that query? seems like that query only can be used to update one by one. really appreciate your help. UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TRY] 
 SET Target_Hire_Date = convert(nvarchar,day(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE)) + '/'
 + convert(nvarchar,MONTH(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE)) + '/' +
 convert(nvarchar,RIGHT(YEAR(YOUR_EXISTING_DATE),2))

Comment: like this? UPDATE [master].[dbo].[1] 
 SET Target_Hire_Date = convert(nvarchar,day(Target_Hire_Date)) + '/'
 + convert(nvarchar,MONTH(Target_Hire_Date)) + '/' +
 convert(nvarchar,RIGHT(YEAR(Target_Hire_Date),2)) but it throws an error. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: is Target_Hire_Date datetime column?

Comment: ok, you do not need (and you can't) to change the format of Target_Hire_Date in the table in that way, but you can run a query with the preferred format ( as output ) as needed.